# How can I assign a material based on CSV data?

Tags: python, materials, linked-data, csv

Is it possible to change color of a mesh based on external CSV data?

I have a CSV file with two columns. One column must refer to/identify a mesh in the Blend file, the other columns displays a '1' or a '0'. Based on the '1' or '0', I want to assign two materials (green and red) to this mesh.

Do you guys know a add-on or tutorial which (partly) covers my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: these links helped me solve my problem:
[How to add color information from csv file to objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252023/how-to-add-color-information-from-csv-file-to-objects)
https://youtu.be/Xrixs_XuDQo
https://youtu.be/h4kCQQ5tA74

Comment: [related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260148/iterating-through-a-collection-and-assigning-a-material-to-each-object-based-on/260158#260158)

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question, please add it as an answer, or if you feel this question was unnecessary, please delete it.